# Long/Large tables are challenging to edit in the traditional SE editor

Tags: support, editor, tables

While I suspect the "WYSIWYG" editor used in Teams might be helpful here (but Markdown mode there lacks a preview - which for the workflow of many... is sub optimal), currently where there's a large table it looks a little like this on a high resolution screen. I do know the fairly large borders are for readability but... I feel like there could be a better way to manage these super wide plain text posts.

> [image: Screenshot of a Meta post edit screen. This shows the editing modal on top with a CommonMark table markdown, with lines split between 2 lines, and the rendered preview below.]

Admittedly - this is a default and a worst case scenario since I can pull down the edit window to make it longer, but it's still hard to read as each line of this table is spread to two lines, with no particularly clear distinction between them.

I'm not sure what's a good way to mitigate it, but I wonder if there's something that could be done, especially with how useful tables are, that would make it easier to read/write/edit in a plain text mode.

Comment: Markdown mode lacking a preview is something I brought up earlier in a feedback thread to members of the Charcoal team.

Comment: This is one of those "doctor, it hurts when I do this" problems. Long, large tables are not just challenging to edit in the editor. They're also challenging and annoying to read.

Comment: funny that I was talking about the "doctor, it hurts when I do this" problem about something else - In this case though, I didn't do it, and I wanted to fix a non-table related issue. In this *particular* question, I'm not entirely sure how else one would display the information needed in a neat way, either.

Comment: Yes, long lists aren't good fits for the Q&A format. But you knew that already, too. :-)

Answer (score 7):

For the few cases where this is useful, I would just

1. Copy the entire text of the post
2. Paste in your favorite text editor
3. Edit the post there
4. Copy & paste back
5. Profit?